# Using Angular for search inbox (like Google search)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want something like Google search matches. When I type something Google gives me some options which match the words I have typed so far; for example if I type "Rog" it gives me the options of "Rogers", "Rogers Yahoo", "Rogers email", "Rogers Centre" and these suggestions are part of the input box not a separate "list" or.... I know this one is possible with angular. I appreciate it if you can guide me :-)

PS: Sorry I was not able to attach a picture(example of Google search) to clarify!
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two resources available from [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) that can get you started:

From [Angular Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), there's [Typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#typeahead).  This is a fairly lightweight solution with no other external dependencies.  It's also very simple, in that it just provides a simple suggestion list below the input.

The alternative is [AngularJS-native version of Select2 and Selectize](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select).  This is a much more complex version, with many more features.  However, it does have dependencies on *both* the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) libraries.

Comment: Thanks that's great; and do you know for Typehead, in the javascript part how I can pass "$scope.states" values with a web service result?

Comment: The typeahead link is dead, use this one instead: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead